# NSXMLParser:foundCharacters throwing 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'

Tags: ios5, nsstring, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

I have a problem when parsing an XML feed. There are approximately 15 child nodes per parent node. Currently I am parsing all nodes using stringbytrimmingchartersinset: then  NSCharacterset whitespaceandnewline characterset.
Like so:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
        currentElementValue = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

This works great for all but one of the nodes. For this node I want the text to come through as is. I've tried setting up an if statement to treat this particular node differently than the others so I updated to the following.

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

   if ([testingString isEqualToString:@"AdoptionSummary"]) {
       [currentElementValue appendString:string]; //This keeps breaking
        }
    else {
         currentElementValue = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    }
```

however I'm getting an error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'

The error only occurs if I use a combination of stringbytrimmingchartersinset and appendString. However if I use either stringbytrimmingchartersinset or appendString on there own it parses without error.  `currentElementValue` is an NSMutableString so why is this error being thrown?

I've tried looking at this [NSMutableString appendString generates SIGABRT Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414711/nsmutablestring-appendstring-generates-sigabrt-error), and this [error : 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:' --](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233178/error-attempt-to-mutate-immutable-object-with-appendstring) but to no avail.

I would like just 'AdoptionSummary" to append 'as is' while the other 14 are trimmed. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its because `currentElementValue` is declared as `NSString`. Change its type to `NSMutableString`.

If you have declared this string with NSMutableString then you will have to change object creation also. Change below code:

```
currentElementValue = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

With this code:

```
currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

Handle alloc swiftly to avoid memory leak.

Comment: it is actually declared as an NSMutableString in my .h  interface Parser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{     
    KHMAppDelegate *app;
    List *theList;
    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
    
}
property NSString *testingString;

-(id)initParser;


end

Comment: @Apurvu,`currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
` did the trick!! Thanks a million! This project is using ARC, do I still need to mannually dealloc? (sorry for the nOOb questions) Thanks Again!

Comment: No, its not required. Also, accept the answer. So it can help to other persons as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentElementValue = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Simply casting an NSString to an NSMutableString doesn't make it one. Make a mutable copy before modifying it.